# Date to varchar Teradata

Tags: date, teradata, varchar

I try convert date to varchar with help of Calendar table (I need use Calendar table), but I always have the same error Failure 2665 Invalid date. Can you help me please, where is the mistake?

Date format of agr1.Start_date is varchar (20).

`Select
agr1.Start_date
from Agreement agr1
left join Calender cal1 on cast ((cal1.Date (format 'YYYYMM')) as varchar (20)) = agr1.Start_Date`

Example

Table Agreement

```
ID | Start_Date
1  | 21.10.2014
2  | abcd
```

So, I need to compare Start_Date wit Date from Calendar where all dates have the same format of Date. With script I should know that `abcd` doesn't have the same date format as Date from table Calendar.

Thank you

Comment: Start by testing your cast: `select date,cast ((cal1.Date (format 'YYYYMM')) as varchar (20)) from calendar cal1`.  I'm thinking that's where your error is coming in.  Sample data from both tables would also be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't need date from Calendar table in select. I should just know which date from table Agreement has the same date format as date from table Calendar. I use this method because of next steps (another script) where I filter right date format (the same as from the table Calendar) and wrong date (that doesn't have the same date format as date from table Calendar, there can be decimal, varchar and etc. values).

Comment: Why are you formatting the date in your calendar table YYYYMM when the start_date column is DD.MM.YYYY?

Comment: i tried with YYYYMMDD and with DD.MM.YYYY and i have the same error 2665...

Comment: The only column you are treating as a date data type is the date column in Calendar.  That's why I made the earlier suggestion, to see if this column is throwing the error you're getting.

Comment: I found mistake :) it should be `select cal1.Date from Agreement agr1 left join Calender cal1 on cast ((cal1.Date (format 'DD.MM.YYYY')) as varchar (20)) = agr1.Start_Date`. Thank you, Andrew :)